# What happens if the input voltage of a low dropout regulator is under the rated minimum voltage?

Tags: power-supply, voltage-regulator, ldo

I am not that familiar with regulators, so, I want to know what happens if the input voltage is under the rated minimum voltage? Does it give zero volts or something under the rated voltage? If it's not zero volts, is there any type that gives 0v or acts like an open circuit in that case ?

there is another similar question but it's not that specific. what I want here is a mention of any type that goes open circuit when the input voltage is under the rated minimum voltage

Comment: Please specify the type of regulator, as they behave differently if lacking power. Also read the "Related" articles in the right-most column. Some will drop the Vout if Vin drops too low, some will shut off, and some will pull more current to keep Vout study until it has to shut off.

Comment: Seems to me this question has been asked before. Anyone remember?

Comment: Actually, I am asking to know the types,would you please mention a type that shuts off when the input is low and type that draws more current?

Comment: It seems like this question is turning into a request for a product recommendation, these are not considered on-topic in the [help center](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Your questions are confusing. A supply that is OFF and has a diode at the output is "open circuit". It can neither source nor sink current.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[I found this LDO regulator](http://cds.linear.com/docs/en/datasheet/3645f.pdf) that pulls more current to maintain the output voltage until the input drops below a certain value, then it shuts OFF. This is perfect for battery operated devices who's battery voltage drops while in use, but at some point the battery is too low, so it should shut off. Part number: LT3645.

Installing a rectifier in the output makes it an 'open' circuit 'OR' gate, neither sourcing or sinking current if the regulator is OFF.

Answer (score 0):

What the output voltage will do when the regulator's input voltage exceeds either its low voltage or high voltage limits depends on the design of the regulator.

There are regulator circuits with outputs which can short the load or let it go open-circuit when the regulator's input voltage falls out of the acceptable input window, So what is it you want to do?

Comment: mention a type that goes open-circuit, please.

Comment: I will if you'll say what it is that you're trying to do.

Comment: powering a load with batteries, specially a router.

Comment: This is not a parts reccommendation service.